# jquery circle progress с разным значением

Tags: html, jquery

Использую [jquery-asPieProgress](https://github.com/thecreation/jquery-asPieProgress) для создания circle progress svg:

```js
if($('.pie_progress').length){

  $('.pie_progress').asPieProgress({
    namespace: 'pie_progress',
    barsize: '6',
    trackcolor: '#cbcbcb',
    numberCallback: function(n) {


      if($(this).hasClass('count-num')){
        console.log('num');
        return n;
      }

      if($(this).hasClass('count-percentage')){
        //const percentage = Math.round(this.getPercentage(n));
        console.log('pers');
        return n + "%";
      }
    },

  });

  $('.pie_progress').asPieProgress('start');
}
```

```css
.count {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-asPieProgress@0.4.7/dist/css/asPieProgress.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-asPieProgress@0.4.7/dist/jquery-asPieProgress.min.js"></script>
  
  
  
  <div class="pie_progress count-num count" role="progressbar" data-goal="257" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="300">
    <div class="pie_progress__number count-number">257</div>
    <div class="pie_progress__label count-label">
      Просто число
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="pie_progress count-percentage count" role="progressbar" data-goal="97" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
    <div class="pie_progress__number count-number">97</div>
    <div class="pie_progress__label count-label">
      Данные в процентах
    </div>
  </div>
```

Но отображение может быть как процентов, так и просто цифры. 
Пытаюсь разделить и вывести по классу, но почему-то выводится просто число.

**Вопрос:** как вывести в circle progress svg как просто число, так и проценты?

**p.s:** в первом круге должно быть просто число - `257`, во втором проценты - `97%`.

Comment: Пожалуйста сформулируйте поточней вопрос, лично я ничего вообще не понял чего вы хотите получить, сейчас запуская пример всё рассчитывается верно и "график" отрисовывается в точности от заданных значений как в цифре: 257 от 300, так и в процентах: 97% от 100%

Comment: p.s: в первом круге должно быть просто число - 257, во втором проценты - 97%

Comment: Теперь всё стало предельно ясно, вам нужно по после окончания построения графика обновить текст в `count-number` для чего нужно почитать методы плагина, сейчас попробуем разобраться...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
if ($('.pie_progress').length) {

  $('#pie_progress_number').asPieProgress({
    namespace: 'pie_progress',
    barsize: '6',
    trackcolor: '#cbcbcb',
    numberCallback: function(n) {
      return n;
    },
  });
  
  $('#pie_progress_percent').asPieProgress({
    namespace: 'pie_progress',
    barsize: '6',
    trackcolor: '#cbcbcb',
    numberCallback: function(n) {
      'use strict';
      const percentage = Math.round(this.getPercentage(n));
      return `${percentage}%`;
    },
  });

  $('.pie_progress').asPieProgress('start');
}
```

```css
.count {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-asPieProgress@0.4.7/dist/css/asPieProgress.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-asPieProgress@0.4.7/dist/jquery-asPieProgress.min.js"></script>

<div class="pie_progress count" role="progressbar" data-goal="257" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="300" id="pie_progress_number">
  <div class="pie_progress__number count-number"></div>
  <div class="pie_progress__label count-label"></div>
</div>
  
<div class="pie_progress count" role="progressbar" data-goal="97" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" id="pie_progress_percent">
  <div class="pie_progress__number count-number"></div>
  <div class="pie_progress__label count-label"></div>
</div>
```